# How to Hide the MenuBar in Tight VNC?

Tags: c#, vnc

I am using TightVNC to establish the connection, by an external program which passes the arguments to TightVNC.exe like,

```
 <profiles>
<profile name="Home" remoteHost="somewhere.somehost.com"
  viewerProgram="C:\Program Files\TightVNC\vncviewer.exe"
  arguments="-compresslevel 9 -quality 6 {H}::{P}"
  connectionMode="SSH">
  <parameters>
  </parameters>
</profile>
```

which is working perfectly. When the connection is done, i am getting the viewer window where i can see the menu bar of TightVNC Viewer. I dont want the user to do anything, i want to hide the menu bar ?? Is there any ways to pass an argument for that?? If not how ?

Comment: C#, wtf, how is this C#?

Comment: like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/securevncviewer.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be done by modifying the source code of vnc. which i did.